# SQL Server query to return 1 row for todays date against multiple column counts

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write an SQL Server query with 1 row as a date stamp for multiple counts of Region for the Customer.  It is returning a row for each case statement.

```
Customer    Region
1           A
2           A
3           B
4           B
5           B

SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111),
case when Region = 'A' then COUNT(Customer) end as 'Region A',
case when Region = 'B' then COUNT(Customer) end as 'Region B',
FROM tbl_Customers
```

Results:

```
Date        Region A    Region B
2017/06/07  2           NULL
2017/06/07  NULL        3
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail, like the data layout.  Understand you are explaining your problem to someone who has never seen your code or data, ever before.  You need to give us more information so we can figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the `CASE` expression inside the aggregation function:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),111) [Date],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Region = 'A' THEN Customer END) [Region A],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Region = 'B' THEN Customer END) [Region B]
FROM tbl_Customers;
```

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks, will answer this as correct.  Great to see the community reaching out to those that need that extra little bit of help